# How to click all items in a NodeList quickly

Tags: javascript, html, nodelist

I need to click on a whole bunch of elements on a webpage. I need to click on them as fast as possible, preferably all at once.

I have the following code:

```
let i = 0;
let v = setInterval(() => {
  i++;document.querySelectorAll(".listing")[i].click();
  if(i >= document.querySelectorAll(".listing").length - 1) clearInterval(v);
}, 1000)
```

However this is just too slow (about 1 second from one click on an element to the next).

I think part of the problem is maybe that it waits for the action that happens when the element is clicked to complete (there is a small animation that plays, however clicking on elements while the animation is playing actually works fine)

Is there a way of doing what I want? or is this as fast as it will get?

Comment: what happens when you decrease that time interval down from 1000 ?

Comment: If you want to click them all at once, then why would you ever have an interval with a long delay in between clicks?

Answer (score -1):

1. Have a shorter interval
2. You are skipping the first one
3. Cache the elements

```js
document.addEventListener("click",(e) => e.target.classList.add("clicked"));
let i = 0;
const listing = document.querySelectorAll(".listing");
const length = listing.length;
let v = setInterval(() => {
  listing[i].click();
  i++;
  if (i >= length) clearInterval(v);
}, 10)
```

```css
.clicked { color: green; }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="listing">Listing</a><br/>
```